# Key out the background of a green screen video using Adobe JavaScript

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-flash, adobe-cs4

I am trying to key out the background of a green screen video using Adobe JavaScript but when I render and export the video as PNG sequences the PNG are appearing with a black background.

Can anyone please help me with getting the control of toggle transparency grid using the script so that I can retain the trasparency in the image?

That's how I am thinking to solve the issue in hand. Anyway I am exporting the PNGs as rgb+alpha with millions of color+ settings on.